# How many epochs does scikit learn use when cross validating?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I'm doing some model cross validation with scikit learn in time series data where a Multi Layer Perceptron is trained with Keras. (We are able to use cross_val_score from scikit learn thanks to the keras wrapper).

Basically using:

```
cross_val_score from scikit learn
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
```

The issue is I don't understand how many epochs its using on each training.

Let me explain with an example. Assume `X_train` has 1779 rows and we are using `tscv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=15)`.

We execute:

```
cross_val_score(model,X_train,y_train,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',cv=tscv)
```

And while calculating this line, it would show something like this:
[image: Training example]

So how many epochs is using for the training of each split?
By training of each split I mean 114/114 would be one split, 225/225 would be the second split, etc.
Is it using just epoch=1, because it trains it too fast? is this configurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume the number of epochs is definied by the default value of the `model`you are using. Normally you can configure that step in your keras model like:

```
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=10)
```

In the line:

```
cross_val_score(model,X_train,y_train,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',cv=tscv)
```

You cannot change it directly as `cross_val_score`doesn't have this option as you can see in the docs:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html

For a better understanding of your model set-up you could provide us more code.

Comment: You are right. The only way to be sure though, was to use verbose=2  inside KerasRegressor and GridSearchCV, because then you'll actually see the epochs when its running.